# How to display ContentView in a CollectionView in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I am trying to use an ObservableCollection of controls (ContentViews) in a CollectionView. The collection of ContentViews are currently being created and populated in the ctor of my ContentPage. I then set the ItemSource of the CollectionView to the property on the page that hold the ObservableCollection. My problem is that the ContentViews do not display at all.

Here is the XAML code from the ContentPage:

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyPolicies}">
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                        <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                               Text="My Policies"
                               FontSize="Small"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.Header>
            </CollectionView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Here is the code in the ContentPage constructor that creates ContentViews and adds them to the collection bound to the CollectionView :

```
    public partial class TestCollectionView : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView> MyPolicies { get; private set; } = null;

        public TestCollectionView()
        {
            IList<ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView> sourcePolicies = new List<ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView>();
            CreateMyPolicies(sourcePolicies);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateMyPolicies(IList<ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView> sourcePolicies)
        {
            //
            sourcePolicies.Add(new ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView());

            sourcePolicies.Add(new ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView());

            sourcePolicies.Add(new ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView());

            //
            MyPolicies = new ObservableCollection<ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView>(sourcePolicies);
        }
    }
```

Here is the ContentView I'm using. You will notice that it has values set as defaults:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NGIC_XAML.Controls.CardViews.ThreeLineThreeColumnCardView">
    <Frame WidthRequest="342"
           BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
           BorderColor="LightGray"
           CornerRadius="5"
           HasShadow="False"
           Padding="8"
           VerticalOptions="Center"
           HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Grid WidthRequest="311" Margin="15, 13, 16, 13">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                   Text="{Binding CardTitle, FallbackValue='R0C0'}"
                   FontAttributes="None"
                   FontSize="14"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardTitleColor, FallbackValue='#333333'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                   Text="{Binding CardAmount, FallbackValue='R0C1'}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   FontSize="16"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardAmountColor, FallbackValue='#53585B'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
                   Text="{Binding CardAmount, FallbackValue='R0C2'}"
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   FontSize="16"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardAmountColor, FallbackValue='#53585B'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="{Binding CardDate, FallbackValue='R1C0'}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardDateColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding CardComment, FallbackValue='R1C1'}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardCommentColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="{Binding CardComment, FallbackValue='R1C2'}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardCommentColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />

            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
                   Text="{Binding CardDate, FallbackValue='R2C0'}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardDateColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"
                   Text="{Binding CardComment, FallbackValue='R2C1'}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardCommentColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
            <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"
                   Text="{Binding CardComment, FallbackValue='R2C2'}"
                   FontSize="12"
                   TextColor="{Binding CardCommentColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="End" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</ContentView>
```

And this is what the ContentView looks like in its raw state:

[image: raw card view]

So, my question is how do I get the collection of "cards" to display in the CollectionView on my ContentPage?

UPDATE
Added to the ContentPage:

```
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <cards:ThreeLineCardView />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

UPADTE Demonstrate that the pre-populated card (a ContentView) can be displayed in the Grid outside of the CollectionView

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <!--<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding MyPolicies}">
                <CollectionView.Header>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
                        <Label Margin="10,0,0,0"
                               Text="My Policies"
                               FontSize="Small"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </CollectionView.Header>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <cards:ThreeLineCardView />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>-->
            <Grid Padding="10">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <cards:ThreeLineCardView />
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

[image]

Comment: you haven't supplied any template for your CollectionView

Comment: OK< but if I am supplying complete objects to use in the CollectionView, why do I need a template? For example, in the documentaation the CollectionView's ItemSuorce is set to an array of strings that are output without a template.

Comment: because in a simple case it will just use ToString() to generate the output, but this is not a simple case.  You appear to be making it more complex than necessary - I don't think the data binding in your ContentView will work like you want it.  A better approach would be to use your ContentView as the template and your data as the ItemsSource

Comment: I added an ItemTemplate (see the UPDATE to my question) and it still doesn't display. There should be a way to do this without having to include the complete layout of the ContentView in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: Did you change your ItemsSource?  If you're new to this I'd suggest you start with something much simpler, get it to work, then build up from there.

Comment: The ItemsSource is set to a collection of ContentViews, which have been populated already. I then added an ItemTemplate consisting of a Grid with row and column definitions and the only type in the Grid is of the same type as that of the objects in the ItemsSource. There must be a reason the items don't display. I can do it the way you stated, and I have done that already with success, but I am trying to do this so I can reuse the ContentViews in different pages with varying visual layouts. The ContentPage shouldn't need to know how I compose the objects to be displayed.

Comment: just use your ContentView as the template and change your ItemsSource to be your data.  There is no reason you can't reuse the ContentView on multiple pages, with or without a CollectionView.

Comment: I added an update to the post that demonstrates that the ContentView can be displayed just fine in a Grid after having been populated in code. I use the same Grid that I have in the ItemsTemplate in the CollectionView. And, yes, you are correct. I can use the ContentView on multiple pages, but I just can't use it in a CollectionView apparently. My goal is to have the ContentView created and populated without having to restate the layout every time I use it.

Comment: @JNickVA1 Hi , have you solved that , And what is the remained problem ?

Comment: I have concluded that the problem cannot be solved using a collection of ContentViews. I have to resort to explicitly declaring the markup, or layout, for the underlying data in the ItemTemplate. That, unfortunately, is the only solution I see. A real shame that you can't use ContentViews as the data objects. I guess this is a solution, just a rather mundane and inelegant one.

Comment: @JNickVA1 Hi , it is possible . You can use Bindable Layouts to achieve that in CollectionView .

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this is your want . If no , you can comment bellow .

I create a **ContentView** named **CardView** , the xaml code is the same as your shared .

Then used in **Xaml** of **ContentPage** as follow :

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalList">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <appentrytest:CardView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

The **CardViewModel** is :

```
public class CardViewModle
{
    public string CardTitle { set; get; }
    public string CardAmount { set; get; }
    public string CardDate { set; get; }
    public string CardComment { set; get; }
}
```

In **ContentPage** ,set data source for CollectView :

```
public partial class PageFourth : ContentPage
{
    public List<CardViewModle> cardViewModles { set; get; }

    public PageFourth()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        cardViewModles = new List<CardViewModle>();
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "1", CardAmount = "2", CardComment = "one more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "2", CardAmount = "5", CardComment = "two more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "3", CardAmount = "6", CardComment = "three more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "4", CardAmount = "8", CardComment = "four more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "5", CardAmount = "12", CardComment = "five more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "6", CardAmount = "18", CardComment = "six more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "7", CardAmount = "80", CardComment = "seven more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "8", CardAmount = "20", CardComment = "eight more", CardDate = "2020-06-17" });

        collectionView.ItemsSource = cardViewModles;

    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]

======================Update===========================

If want each item of **CollectionView** also can contain a list of Controls , you can use [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) to achieve that .

The **Xaml** of **CardView** as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="AppEntryTest.CardView">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <Frame WidthRequest="342"
               BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
               BorderColor="LightGray"
               CornerRadius="5"
               HasShadow="False"
               Padding="8"
               VerticalOptions="Center"
               HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Grid WidthRequest="311"
                  Margin="15, 13, 16, 13">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="60*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="{Binding CardTitle, FallbackValue='R0C0'}"
                       FontAttributes="None"
                       FontSize="14"
                       TextColor="{Binding CardTitleColor, FallbackValue='#333333'}"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding CardAmount, FallbackValue='R0C1'}"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"
                       FontSize="16"
                       TextColor="{Binding CardAmountColor, FallbackValue='#53585B'}"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Orientation="Vertical"
                            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CommetList}">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                       Text="{Binding CardDate, FallbackValue='R1C0'}"
                                       FontSize="12"
                                       TextColor="{Binding CardDateColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                                       WidthRequest="300"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding CardComment, FallbackValue='R1C1'}"
                                       FontSize="12"
                                       TextColor="{Binding CardCommentColor, FallbackValue='#70777C'}"
                                       WidthRequest="900"
                                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </Frame>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Also used in **ContentPage** :

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionView"
                        ItemsLayout="VerticalList">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <appentrytest:CardView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here need to create a **CardCommentModel** :

```
public class CardCommentModel
{
    public string CardDate { set; get; }
    public string CardComment { set; get; }
}
```

And modify **CardViewModle** as follow :

```
public class CardViewModle
{
    public string CardTitle { set; get; }
    public string CardAmount { set; get; }

    public List<CardCommentModel> CommetList { set; get; }
}
```

Then in **ContenPage** , setting data for `CollectView` :

```
public partial class PageFourth : ContentPage
{
    public List<CardViewModle> cardViewModles { set; get; }

    public PageFourth()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<CardCommentModel> cardCommentModelsOne = new List<CardCommentModel>();
        cardCommentModelsOne.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "13:12:16", CardComment = "comment one" });
        cardCommentModelsOne.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "13:15:16", CardComment = "comment two" });

        List<CardCommentModel> cardCommentModelsTwo = new List<CardCommentModel>();
        cardCommentModelsTwo.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "14:12:16", CardComment = "comment one" });
        cardCommentModelsTwo.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "15:22:16", CardComment = "comment two" });
        cardCommentModelsTwo.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "15:42:16", CardComment = "comment three" });

        List<CardCommentModel> cardCommentModelsThree = new List<CardCommentModel>();
        cardCommentModelsThree.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "15:32:16", CardComment = "comment one" });
        cardCommentModelsThree.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "15:29:11", CardComment = "comment two" });
        cardCommentModelsThree.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "16:12:16", CardComment = "comment three" });
        cardCommentModelsThree.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "17:28:19", CardComment = "comment four" });
        cardCommentModelsThree.Add(new CardCommentModel() { CardDate = "18:42:26", CardComment = "comment five" });

        cardViewModles = new List<CardViewModle>();
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "First Title", CardAmount = "Count : "+cardCommentModelsOne.Count.ToString(), CommetList= cardCommentModelsOne});
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "Second Title", CardAmount = "Count : " + cardCommentModelsTwo.Count.ToString(), CommetList= cardCommentModelsTwo });
        cardViewModles.Add(new CardViewModle() { CardTitle = "Third Title", CardAmount = "Count : " + cardCommentModelsThree.Count.ToString(), CommetList= cardCommentModelsThree });

        collectionView.ItemsSource = cardViewModles;

    }
}
```

The effect :

[image]