# How can I execute a method after a content page is visible in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, performance, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin Forms app made for android as of now, I have a **stack layout that gets populated based on a list that needs to fetch data from local sqlite DB.** The data is around 200 rows. The stack needs to be populated when the ContentPage appears in foreground.
Since this process takes a bit of time, **the navigation to this page is taking some time** which leads to poor performance of app.
I have added that `refresh` method in **constructor of page** and also have tried putting it in **OnAppearing override method**. But the transition occurs only when the stack is populated.
Is there any way to **view the page to the user first** (make navigation happen) and **then populate the stack?**

````
    {
        private string shipmentId;
        
        public ScanOrderPage( string shipmentID)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            shipmentId = shipmentID;
            TapGestureRecognizer tapEvent = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapEvent.Tapped += Scan_Button_OnClicked;
            clickFrame.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapEvent);
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            await Initiator();
        }

        private async Task Initiator()
        {
            Indicator.IsVisible = true;
            bool allGood;
            if (!await App.Database.IsShipmentPresent(shipmentId))
            {
                int getBox = await new ShipmentBoxes().Get(shipmentId);
                allGood = getBox == 1;
            }
            else allGood = true;

            if (!allGood) return;
            await Populate();
            
            Indicator.IsVisible = false;
        }

        private async Task Populate()
        {
            BoxListStack.Children.Clear();
            var shipmentData = await App.Database.GetShipmentBoxes(shipmentId);
            if (shipmentData == null) return;
                
            ShipmentIDText.Text = shipmentId;
            FromText.Text = shipmentData?.FirstOrDefault()?.From;
            ToText.Text = shipmentData?.FirstOrDefault()?.To;
            TotalBoxesText.Text = "Total Boxes: " + shipmentData.Count.ToString();
            int scanCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < shipmentData.Count; i++)
            {
                string boxCode = shipmentData.ElementAt(i).BoxCode;
                if (shipmentData.ElementAt(i).Scanned) scanCount += 1;
                else
                {
                    int foo = boxCode.LastIndexOf("-", StringComparison.Ordinal);
                    boxCode = boxCode.Substring(0, foo + 1) + "XXXX";
                }
                
                BoxListStack.Children.Add(new ScanBoxes(shipmentData.ElementAt(i).Scanned)
                {
                    Subject = shipmentData.ElementAt(i).Subject + " " + shipmentData.ElementAt(i).SubjectClass,
                    BoxCode = boxCode
                });
                
            }

            ScanStatusText.Text = "Boxes Scanned: " + scanCount.ToString() + " | Boxes Pending: " +
                                  (shipmentData.Count - scanCount).ToString();
        }```
````

Comment: fetch the data in a task that you fire in OnAppearing

Comment: @Jason I am doing that. I am fetching all the data and populating the stack in a Task in OnAppearing method.

Comment: it really helps if you post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason Thanks. I have added the code. `Populate` populates the stack with contentView from data fetched in the same Task.

Comment: Use RemainingItemsThreshold like this blog [infinite-scroll](https://doumer.me/infinite-scroll-with-the-xamarin-forms-collection-view/)

Comment: Shaw, @Jason, multiple answers here recommend infinite scrolling but I don't understand how will infinite scrolling solve my problem. Can you please help??

Comment: you need to follow Ivan's advice and run your code on a separate Task, not just using await

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is wrong to view that your problem is in timing. Your problem is that you are executing too much long running code on the UI thread which freezes UI. Obviously you could postpone that to the moment when the page is displayed (for example using the `Timer`), but the problem with frozen UI would remain just it would appear in a bit less annoying form.

As your code appears to have lines that require to be running on UI thread in order to avoid crashes I can't go line by line and fix the problem.

However to run on non-UI thread you use `Task.Run` . If you need to switch to the UI thread after that you use `InvokeOnMainThread`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the advice. I'll get on it and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try infinite scrolling. Load as you scroll through the list

https://youtu.be/sZq8K_64bc0

Comment: please do not post answers that are just links to offsite content

Comment: The stack is inside a scrollview. Stack gets populated by a contentView which gets its data from local DB

Comment: Well you could just place your contentview cards inside a collectionview like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416052/how-to-display-contentview-in-a-collectionview-in-xamarin-forms then try infinite scrolling